# Database not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[projectcostingfile table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl1qo.png) I have checked my sql query several times and make sure that the names are correct. Still not inserting.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO projectcostingfile (material) VALUES ('".$selected."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert);
}
}
}
```

The variable $selected is echoed correctly. There is no error when I run the code too. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks for your help. The problem lies with my table structure like what some of you mentioned. I set the column fields to NOT NULL. Therefore inserting into only 1 column would not have any INSERT record shown in the database.

Comment: What is the schema for your table `projectcostingfile`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: where is $conn variable, have you defined $conn variable? there is connection to the database or not?

Comment: @PrateekVerma yes! I'm pretty sure $conn is fine. I used $conn for other other query on the same page and is working fine.

Comment: @kampangala Nope. I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Are you using any caching server like Varnish ?

Comment: I have given a answer, please try that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely there is nothing wrong with your PHP code, but it does not comply DB schema. Check error.log file on your PHP server and it will show you lot of DB errors, concerning NULL values.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO projectcostingfile SET material = '".$selected."'";
```

Also use 'or die(mysqli_error());' after mysqli_query to identify the error..

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to Replace Below Syntax : 

$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO projectcostingfile (`material`) VALUES ('".$selected."')";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still the same result. No error, nothing is inserted into the database.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO projectcostingfile (material) VALUES ('".$selected."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert);
}
}
}

above code is your correct you just put following code such as post array

<input type="text" name="check_list[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
$check_values = implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);
echo $check_values;
$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO projectcostingfile (material) VALUES ('".$check_values."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert);

}
}
```

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot insert `only one field` `material` in your given table. From the picture shown in your question, `all fields in your table should not be null`. So i think we cannot added rows in that table by filling only one field. You have to insert all the fields or change the null status to `yes` of all other field except `material`.

I think this might work if you don't have any other options.

Comment: I think this is the better way. If you have set your fields not null and the `INSERT` keyword basically creates a record. so you need to fill other columns with values or defaults. Otherwise there's no problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions have been given above. But i would like to tell you that even a faced such issue were my **`code, Mysql connnection, query , php codes` Where right but in `myphpadmin` inside my database i have accidentally added a 'black Space' near sql table or column name because to which my sql query was not giving me the error but also not inserting the code**.i recommend you to try this.

If doesn't work than my bad.